# setInterval unlimited rerendering react full component. Why does this happens and how can I solve it?

Tags: reactjs

This is my react code. It is making the component infinite rerender:

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60)
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

console.log("object");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are clearing the interval only on component unmount, which will happen only when the users leaves the page.

Maybe this is what you need? I am clearing the interval when it reaches 0. But for that I must use a ref, i cannot use the state in the setInterval, because it will have only the initial value:

```
export default function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(5);
  const secondsRef = useRef(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (secondsRef.current < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

      secondsRef.current = secondsRef.current - 1;
      setSeconds((seconds) => seconds - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  console.log("running", new Date());

  return <p> {seconds < 0 ? "Time is up!" : seconds} </p>;
}
```

Comment: And you used useRef to avoid the stale closure issue of seconds, right? nice.